# Deprecated touch operations on mobile apps

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cordova, dom-events

In past mobile apps that I developed, I found that the `click` event did not work as expected in all devices (for example: in games in which the user had to tap/click quickly on the screen, instead of triggering the `click` event, the double click was triggered), and using `touchstart` gave better results for what I wanted.

Since then, I started listening to the `touchstart` event instead of `click`; but testing on Chrome, I got the following warning message in the JS console:

> Performing operations that require explicit user interaction on touchstart events is deprecated and will be removed in M54, around October 2016. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5649871251963904 for more details.

I visited the linked page (and the links inside it) and it seems that this new behavior is to avoid certain unwanted actions, and in particular to avoid third-party `iframes` or ads (my app has none) from opening pop-ups. I tried changing the event to `touchend` (as one of the links stated "*The touchend event will continue to behave as before*"), but got a similar warning message.

And my questions:

- Is this something that only affects Chrome, or will it affect my web apps (with Cordova/Phonegap) for Android and iOS?
- What event should I use to replace `touchstart` and avoid the issues I faced in the past? I could go back to `click`, but fast clicking/tapping would still be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating Cordova app, you target different OS versions, Android 5 and up has auto updating webview based on Chromium, so that problem will probably affect your apps.

But since Chrome 32, when using this viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`, the click delay should go away (see [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away?hl=en)), so you could safely use `click` event. Latest webviews on android 5 and 6 are based on Chromium 52.

You can also use [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library that will "fix" the click delay only where it's necessary